# Least possible value of $k$ for which $f(x)=x^2+kx+1$ is increasing on $[1,2]$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, quadratics, maxima-minima

> Find the least possible value of $k$ for which $f(x)=x^2+kx+1$ is increasing on $[1,2]$

$$
f(x)=x^2+kx+1\\
f'(x)=2x+k\geq0\implies \boxed{k\geq-2x}\\
1\leq x\leq2\implies -2\leq-x\leq-1\implies-4\leq-2x\leq-2\implies k>-4\\
f(2)>f(1)\implies k>-3
$$

The solution given in my reference is $x=-2$, how do I obtain it mathematically ?

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the inequality might help:

$$
k\geq -2x\iff -k/2\leq x
$$
If $1\leq x\leq 2$, it's clear one must take $-k/2\leq 1$, from which the answer follows.

Comment: how come $x\geq 1$ & $x\geq -k/2\implies -k/2\leq 1$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 $x$ isn't a fixed value greater than or equal to $1.$  It may refer to any value $x \geq 1$.  For instance, you may set $x=1$.  This gives the correct candidate $k \geq -2.$  From here, you assume $k \geq -2$ and $1\leq x \leq 2$ and show $k \geq -2x.$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^2+kx+1$$
$$f'(x)=2x+k\geq0\implies \boxed{k\geq-2x}$$

It's good up to here, but since we must have $k \geq -2x$ for $x \in [1, 2]$ it suffices to have $k = -2$.

Mathematically, if we have
$$k = -2$$
and
$$1 \leq x \leq 2$$

Then,
$$1 \leq x$$
$$-2x \leq -2$$
$$-2x \leq k$$
$$2x + k \geq 0$$

To prove that $-2$ is the lowest possible value for $k$, suppose
$$k < -2$$
and let
$$x = 1$$
Then,
$$2x + k < 0$$
which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: how do I mathematically show this ?

Comment: I think this proves for $k=-2$ the function is increasing in the given domain. But how do you find $k=-2$ is the least value possible in the first place mathematically ?

Comment: Ok, new and improved version up now, with a proof that $k \geq -2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is clear. Because by the condition $k》-2x$ the maximum  value  of $-2x$ is the least value of k. The maximum  value  of $-2,x$ is $-2$.